# How to change file owner in AIX?

Tags: users, aix, chown

How can I change a owner of a file in AIX? I created a file using my personal account and then I tried to change user for this file:

```
chown rootuser myfile.csv
chown: myfile.csv: Operation not permitted.
```

Then I changed to root user

```
sudo /usr/bin/su - rootuser
```

and tried to change the owner of this file

```
chown rootuser myfile.csv
chown: myfile.csv: Not owner
```

How can I change the owner of this file?

Comment: You are not allowed to change the ownership of any file you own to another user: this opens up a can of worms in terms of security. As for `root` not being able to do that, this is really strange. By any chance, are you in a corporate environment where you authenticate with something like NIS/LDAP? Is this file local to your box or is it from a network-shared partition? What is the file `Bill_Item_Tag_data.csv`? Is `myfile.csv` a symbolic link?

Comment: Could you add some outputs to your question? <pre>id rootuser</pre> and <pre>lsuser rootuser</pre>.

Comment: @JosephR I edited my question.

Comment: try sudo chown rootuser myfile.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to run `chown` as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file/27374#27374).

Root means root: the user with user ID 0. If this `rootuser` is a user who has the permission to run commands as root by using `sudo`, that's not good enough. What `rootuser` can do is to run `sudo chown …` — the `chown` command must be run by root, the `rootuser` itself has no particular privileges.

Comment: Ok, I guess my rootuser is not really a root. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios for this question.
A file which is owned by you and you want others to access then you go on with `chmod` command granting permission for the file while you still hold the Owner access. which means other users can view the file contents, edit the file contents, but not delete the file.

Suppose if you are leaving office and you want to give Ownership rights to one of your colleague during your absence then you go for `chown` command.

`chown username filename`- will make the changes to user
`chown username:groupname` - will make changes to user as well as group.

`username` above refers to the username for which you want to change ownership details.