# Seems that chown is allowed to non root user

Tags: permissions, root, group, chown

We are using LDAP authentication and probably another things that I did not understand well, in our company so maybe the following questions are result of this. I have found strange behavior of `chown` command, and I do not know if this is normal. Here is my scenario:

GID of user mark is SK001936 and owner grup of home dir of mark is SK001778, as you can see they are not the same.
The group SK001778 is allowed all operations (rwx) with home dir of user mark as owner (mark) has:

```
[mark@machine ~]$ id
uid=48447(mark) gid=41795(SK001936) groups=40119(SUB_SK001936_PPS),41795(SK001936)
[mark@machine ~]$ ls -lad .
drwxrwxr-x   6 mark SK001778  4096 Oct 10 13:30 .
```

GID of user michael and mark are both SK001936:

```
[michael@machine mark]$ id
uid=40570(michael) gid=41795(SK001936) groups=40119(SUB_SK001936_PPS),41795(SK001936)
[mark@machine ~]$ id
uid=48447(mark) gid=41795(SK001936) groups=40119(SUB_SK001936_PPS),41795(SK001936)
```

user michael cannot create file in home dir of user mark.
It is the matter of that michael do not belongs to group (SK001778) which has the full (rwx) access to mark's home directory:

```
[michael@machine mark]$ touch michael
touch: cannot touch `michael': Permission denied
```

Under normal circumstances the user cannot issue the chown even if he is the owner of the file.
However in this example the owner of home directory (mark) is able to change the owner group of his own home directory (and thus allows the users belonging to this group access to his home dir):

```
[mark@machine ~]$ chown mark:SK001936 .
```

The group which now has access to mark home dir is thus the same group as GID of michael, hence the michael is now allowed to create/delete files/folders in mark's home dir:

```
[michael@machine mark]$ touch michael
```

mark is unable to change back the group ownership of his home dir (remember only root is allowed to issue chown accoring to this: [why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file)):

```
[mark@machine ~]$ chown mark:SK001778 .
chown: changing ownership of `.': Operation not permitted
```

My question is: how is possible that mark was able to change the group ownership of his home dir even when si [declared](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file) that chown can be issued only by root. The box is RedHat 5.6.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `chown` in a manner that changes only the group, then it acts the same as `chgrp`.  The owner of a file or directory can change the group to any group he is a member of.

It works like that because both the `chown` and `chgrp` commands use the same underlying `chown` syscall, which allows changing both owner and group.  The syscall is what applies the permission check.  The only difference between the `chown` and `chgrp` commands is the syntax you use to specify the change you want to make.

Mark can't change the group back to SK001778 because he isn't a member of group SK001778 (and he isn't root, which isn't restricted by group membership).

Answer (score 2):

Users can use it to change groups, assuming they are in one of these groups.

#### Example

Say I'm in the following groups:

```
$ groups
saml vboxusers jupiter newgrp
```

And I have a file:

```
$ ls -l | grep afile
-rw-rw-r--   1 saml saml        0 Oct 10 11:29 afile
```

so I change the group of this file like so:L

```
$ chown saml.newgrp afile 

$ ls -l | grep afile
-rw-rw-r--   1 saml newgrp        0 Oct 10 11:29 afile
```

You can also use `chown` like this:

```
$ chown .saml afile 

$ ls -l|grep afile
-rw-rw-r--   1 saml saml        0 Oct 10 11:29 afile
```