# Force new files to inherit specified ownership and permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

There is a directory I have

`/var/new_share/KRA2017/Prateek`

with these contents

```
-rwx------  1 superadmin   superadmin    0 Feb 16 15:14 file1.txt*
-rwx------  1 superadmin   superadmin    0 Feb 16 15:14 file2.txt*
-rwx------  1 superadmin   superadmin    0 Feb 16 15:15 file3.txt*
-rwx------  1 superadmin   superadmin    0 Feb 16 15:15 file4.txt*
```

in

`/var/new_share/KRA2017/`

The permission and ownership of directory `/var/new_share/KRA2017/Prateek` is

```
dr-xrwx--- 2 prateekkaien superadmin 4096 Feb 16 15:15 Prateek/
```

i.e the group owner can only write and user can only read and execute.

Whenever a file is being written by user `superadmin`the user and group owner of the files becomes superadmin as shown here. `file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt` are written by user `superadmin`.

I want the user owner of the files to stick to prateekkaien with the same permissions r-x and the group owner to be superadmin with rwx permission like its parent directory.

How is this possible?

Basically all I want is for the files to inherit the owner, group, and permissions of the parent directory.

Comment: You can force the group ownership  with the setgid bit on directories, but it works [only for the group](http://superuser.com/questions/471844/why-is-setuid-ignored-on-directories), not for the user. So the question becomes: why do you want to change user ownership, too, and what do you hope to achieve by that?

Comment: I want the user to be able to read/view the file. When a file is being created it is being user-owned by 'superadmin' with permission rwx

Basically all I want is, the files to inherit the same user and groups and same permissions and ownerships as of the parent directory

Comment: You could swap user and group to achieve this: Create a group `prateekkaien` (or use an existing one), use `setgid` as described by @dirkt, set the permissions accordingly and leave the user untouched.

Comment: As a further example, you normally just make groups according to the necessary roles, and then assign users to it. For example, my `/usr/local` as a setgid of `staff`, and I'm member of `staff`, so I can work with files below `/usr/local` any way I want. If some other user who is also a member of `staff` does the same, I don't care, because as a member of the same group, I can modify his files etc.

Comment: By this, will not the user 'prateekkaien' gain access of rwx as of the group ? 

The superuser is the administrator. It can create and modify files but the user can only view/read it.

I didnt get what it says above

Answer (score 1):

On Unix the owner of a file is the user, who created it.

There are several questions, which already answer this and explain why:

- [Why can't a normal user `chown` a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file)
- [Setting default username and group for files in directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99079/setting-default-username-and-group-for-files-in-directory)
- [How do you set the default user in Linux for file creation?](https://superuser.com/questions/361536/how-do-you-set-the-default-user-in-linux-for-file-creation)

Comment: I found a funny case. System without entry for the user in /etc/passwd. When the user creates file or directory the owner is root.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to enforce `r-x` access to owner user `prateekkaien`, and `rwx` access to owner group `superadmin`. This won't work because `prateekkaien`, as file owner, has full permission over it and it can simply do a `chmod u+r` to gain write access to the file.

What you could do is set the SGID bit on the directory, as @dirkt and @Murphy  commented, so all newly created files will have `superadmin` as owner group.