# SUID bit ignored when creating files / directories

Tags: setgid, suid

I've set the SUID & SGID bit on a folder belonging to user *foo* with `sudo chmod g+s myfolder` & `sudo chmod u+s myfolder`

```
drwsr-sr-x 24 foo www-data 4,0K Okt 25 16:17 myfolder
```

Then I went inside and created a folder with `sudo mkdir xyz`, but the user of the folder gets overwritten with `root` while the group was protected successfully.

```
drwxr-sr-x  2 root  www-data 4,0K Okt 25 16:24 xyz
```

I expect the user to be protected, it should stay at `foo` after executing `sudo mkdir xyz`. What have I missed?

Comment: is setuid supposed to work to override the owner of the created file in some system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting default username and group for files in directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99079/setting-default-username-and-group-for-files-in-directory)

Answer (score 0):

- `xyz` This doesn't look like a problem because you used `sudo`
- which of course should be `root` instead of `foo`, and you set `chmod g+s myfolder` so it's `www-data`
- `sudo` is only used when needed, not for every command, you can try `mkdir xyz`

Answer (score 0):

If you are user `foo` then without the SUID/SGID bits the permissions will work exactly as you seem to want:

```
ls -ld myfolder myfolder/xyz
drwxr-xr-x 3 foo www-data 4096 Oct 25 16:00 myfolder
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo www-data 4096 Oct 25 16:00 myfolder/xyz/
```

SUID doesn't apply to directories, so the directory will be created with you as the owner. With SGID the group carries through, even if the creator/owner is not a member of that group.

However, if ACLs are available on the target filesystem you can use them to allow user `foo` and/or members of group `www-data` access to the directories regardless of the visible owner and group.