# Is it possible to create a file with the privileges of other users?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I am a user of the root account on the server named A.
And I also own the accounts of user1 and user2.

When I create a file or directory in the account of user1,
I want the owner of the file to be user2.

Setting the group is possible by using the setuid: [Setting default permissions for newly created files and sub-directories under a directory in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a).

For the user account, is there any way?

Example. Make file - traditional way:

```
[user1@srv1 tmp]$ id
uid=4001(user1) gid=4001(user1) groups=4001(user1)

[user1@srv1 tmp]$ touch test_user1

[user1@srv1 tmp]$ ls -al test_user1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 2014-01-09 15:24 test_user1
```

Example. Make file - what I want:

```
[user1@srv1 tmp]$ id
uid=4001(user1) gid=4001(user1) groups=4001(user1)

[user1@srv1 tmp]$ touch test_user1

[user1@srv1 tmp]$ ls -al test_user1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user2 user1 0 2014-01-09 15:24 test_user1
```

I **do not** wish to have to change the permissions of the file using the `chown` command.

Comment: You can use su or sudo to run the command as the user you want to be the owner of the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using capabilities (and RHEL does), you can give the user CAP_CHOWN.

See this answer:

[Why can't a normal user `chown` a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u username touch file.name
```

or

```
su username -c touch filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file's user/group properties:

```
chown user2:user1 test_user1
```

The syntax is: `chown <user>:<group> <file or dir>` to change the owner/owner group from a file or folder

Comment: I hope that the file is created, the Owner changed. without chown