# Change ownership of file from a user to another user which the first user controlls

Tags: sudo, chown

I already know I cannot use chown willi-nilly [as a normal user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125785/why-cannot-a-user-change-group-ownership-of-his-own-files) however in my situation I have two users: `user1` and `user2` where `user1` is allowed, by the Sudoers file, to sudo in as `user2`.

Is it still not possible for `user1` to give ownership of the file to `user2`?

The best I have come up with so far is to have `user1` perform:

```
user1@localhost$ sudo --user user2 cp fileOwnedByUser1 /tmp/fileOwnedByUser1
user1@localhost$ rm fileOwnedByUser1
user1@localhost$ sudo --user user2 mv /tmp/fileOwnedByUser1 fileOwnedByUser1
```

However, this seems clunky and ineficient. Is there a better way for `user1` to do this? The only thing that occures to me so far, is to put `user1` as being able to run "chown" as root in the `Sudoers` file.

Comment: Letting user1 run chown as root is a bad idea.  You may as well give them full root access, as chown can be used to get, for example, a setuid shell.

Comment: Perhaps you should review your need to set the ownership, which is really only useful when handling quotas, for example. Why not put the 2 users in the same group and allow group write permissions, or use `setfacl -d -m u:user2:rwx` on a directory so that all files created there by user1 are writable by user2?

Comment: @meuh: Unfortunately, it isn't only usefull when handling quotas. In this case `user1` is setting up and configuring a file structure in `user2`'s home directory. It would be extremely weird and user-unfriendly to have `user2` then have files in their home dir that they don't own.

Comment: I agree. So why isn't user1 using sudo as user2 to create the files in the first place? Can't you do something like having the files in a dir and just tar-copying them whilst user2? Like /etc/skel is copied when users are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that user1 is allowed to run commands as user2 via sudo doesn't matter for the file permission decisions that are taken at a much lower level, in the kernel. There, `chown` is reserved to root (Linux also allows processes with the capability `CAP_CHOWN`, but that doesn't help you because giving a process this capability amounts to indirectly giving it root privileges).

You could write a sudo rule, perhaps with a small wrapper script, that allows user1 to call `chown` on files that belong to user2. The problem is that this is insecure because there would be a race condition between the ownership check on the file and the call to `chown`: user1 (or even a third user, depending on directory permissions) could substitute another file between the check and the action.

You can write a small program that uses the [`fchown` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fchown): open the file, call `lstat`, verify the current ownership, and if everything is fine then call `fchown`. There's no risk of a file substitution here since the check and the action are performed on the same file handle.

Comment: Gilles: Do I understand correctly that you are sugesting that I write a small suid program?

Comment: @timthelion That's the only secure method I can think of, assuming you do need to change ownership (rather than copy and delete, or use ACL).

Comment: I have selected your answer, because I am afraid that you are correct, and that there is no other way to do chowning as a normal user securely besides writing a suid program. However, I will not be taking that route in my final design, because hacking around the problem is actually more practical for me than writing a suid program and having to defend that fact to packagers.