# chown command not working as expected. The command fails even though syntax is right

Tags: shell

I have the following file for which i am the owner .

-rw-r-----    1 hhebburs users            40 Oct  9 15:43 failed_xls

but chown is not working .

/home/hhebburs>chown  mwoods failed_xls

chown: failed_xls: Not owner

What am i doing wrong ?

I understand now that i cant give away files . 
Now my problem  is I have a whole bunch of files with write permissions on them and i am not the root .

Now i can zip the files but the minute i zip the files i become the owner . . After Zipping i still want the owner to be the one who created the file. and not me . Any way that is feasible ?

Comment: @John1024: I understand now that i cant give away files . Now my problem is I have a whole bunch of files with write permissions on them and i am not the root .

Now i can zip the files but the minute i zip the files i become the owner . . After Zipping i still want the owner to be the one who created the file. and not me . Any way that is feasible ?

Answer (score 1):

Users may only run chown if they have the target user and group privileges as explained in detail in the article [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file).

Comment: I understand now that i cant give away files . Now my problem is I have a whole bunch of files with write permissions on them and i am not the root .

Now i can zip the files but the minute i zip the files i become the owner . . After Zipping i still want the owner to be the one who created the file. and not me . Any way that is feasible ?

Comment: You could ask the owner to copy your zip file and then they would become the owner of the copied file, after which you could delete your zip file.