# What does it mean for a folder to have suid permission?

Tags: permissions, suid

I know what it means for a file to have suid permission. It means when other users have execute permission for it, they execute as the owner of the file. But what does it imply when a folder has suid permission? I did some testing and it seems nothing special for the folder. Could anyone help to plain a little? Thanks.

I'm using Oracle Linux 7.6.

```
root:[~]# cat /etc/*release*
Oracle Linux Server release 7.6
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6"
ID="ol"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.6"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:6:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
Oracle Linux Server release 7.6
cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:6:server
root:[~]#
```

Below is my testing on a freshly installed server.

```
root:[~]# pwd
/root
root:[~]# ls -lad /root
dr-xr-x---. 9 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:07 /root
root:[~]# mkdir test
root:[~]# ls -lad test
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:07 test
root:[~]#
root:[~]# useradd a
root:[~]# passwd a
Changing password for user a.
New password:
BAD PASSWORD: The password is a palindrome
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
root:[~]# chmod u+s test
root:[~]#
root:[~]# su - a
[a@localhost ~]$ cd /root/test
-bash: cd: /root/test: Permission denied
[a@localhost ~]$ cd /root
-bash: cd: /root: Permission denied
[a@localhost ~]$ logout
root:[~]#
root:[~]# ls -lad /root
dr-xr-x---. 10 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:07 /root
root:[~]# chmod o+x /root
root:[~]#
root:[~]# su - a
Last login: Fri Aug 16 22:08:54 CST 2019 on pts/0
[a@localhost ~]$ cd /root/test
[a@localhost test]$
[a@localhost test]$ pwd
/root/test
[a@localhost test]$ ls -la .
total 8
drwsr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:07 .
dr-xr-x--x. 10 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:07 ..
[a@localhost test]$ touch file1
touch: cannot touch ‘file1’: Permission denied
[a@localhost test]$ logout
root:[~]#
root:[~]# chmod o+w test/
root:[~]#
root:[~]# su - a
Last login: Fri Aug 16 22:09:31 CST 2019 on pts/0
[a@localhost ~]$
[a@localhost ~]$ cd /root/test
[a@localhost test]$ touch file1
[a@localhost test]$ ls -la
total 8
drwsr-xrwx.  2 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:11 .
dr-xr-x--x. 10 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:07 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 a    a       0 Aug 16 22:11 file1
[a@localhost test]$ mkdir folder1
[a@localhost test]$ ls -la
total 12
drwsr-xrwx.  3 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:11 .
dr-xr-x--x. 10 root root 4096 Aug 16 22:07 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 a    a       0 Aug 16 22:11 file1
drwxrwxr-x.  2 a    a    4096 Aug 16 22:11 folder1
[a@localhost test]$
```

As you can see, it seems the files and folders the user `a` created in `/root/test` didn't inherit the owner and group of it. The owner and group is `a` and not `root`. Are there any problems with my testing? I'm new in Linux.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. Does this apply to all Linux distribution like Ubuntu? What is the distribution that @m242 mentioned in his answer? It seems that Linux does use suid for directories.

Comment: It applies to all Linux distributions, because this is how the Linux kernel is.

Comment: There is a lot of history about these flags - worth reading around the whole subject if you want to lean more about all the different approaches for this. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't mean anything on your Oracle Linux or on any Linux system.

However it *may* have meaning on FreeBSD. Quoting from the [`chmod(2)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) manpage:

> If mode `ISUID` (set UID) is set on a directory, and  the `MNT_SUIDDIR`   option
>        was used in the mount of the file system, then **the   owner of any new files
>        and subdirectories created within  this directory are set to be the same
>        as the owner of that directory**.  If this function is enabled, new directories will inherit the bit from their parents.  Execute bits are removed
>        from the file, and it will not be given to root.  This behavior does not
>        change the requirements for the user to be allowed to write the file, but
>        only the eventual owner after it has been created.  Group inheritance is
>        not affected.
>
> This feature is designed for use on fileservers serving PC    users via ftp,
>        SAMBA, or netatalk.  It provides security holes for shell users and as
>        such should not be used on shell machines, especially on home directories.  **This option  requires the `SUIDDIR` option in the kernel to work.
>        Only UFS file systems support this option.**    For more details of the suid-
>        dir mount option, see mount(8).

This is **not** supported on other *BSD systems like NetBSD or OpenBSD.

Answer (score 6):

[According to the GNU manual,](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html) it means files (including subfolders) created in the directory will inherit its group and user:

> On a few systems, a directory’s set-user-ID bit has a similar effect on the ownership of new subfiles and the set-user-ID bits of new subdirectories. These mechanisms let users share files more easily, by lessening the need to use chmod or chown to share new files.

Comment: Since this is Linux, the setuid not doesn't do anything on directories.

Comment: Does anyone know any of these systems that support SUID on directories?

Comment: @Christopher that's my bad, sorry. I edited to include a quote from the manual and included the bit about setgid as well by mistake.

Comment: It might mean that for some systems, but it doesn't mean that for Linux, which the question mentioned. I'm not sure if there is a authoritative documentation about that for Linux specifically.