# How can I allow a user to gift a file to another user?

Tags: permissions, chown

See [Why can't a normal user `chown` a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file) for unrestricted access to chown is a bad idea. However, I want to implement a restricted version of this. I want to allow user adam to give files to user bobby and only allow this transfer.

Comment: Look at `sudoers`.

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to allow user adam to give files to user bobby and only allow this transfer.

To do this, you'd need to have a program that runs as root, makes the necessary checks and changes the owner of a given file. Running as root is easy, you can use `sudo` or a setuid program, getting the checking done right so that the program can't be misused, is harder.

What might work, would be to to: 1) Open the file 2) use `fstat()` to check its owner 3) then `fchown()` to change the owner.

It's necessary to go through an fd to work on the file, as access through the file *name* will not guarantee that the file being checked is the file that is operated on a moment later. The file could be changed in between.

Another choice would be to implement a sort of an "upload service" that would receive the files (their contents) through the network from `adam`, and then create completely new files for `bobby` from the received data.

I don't think either of these exist as ready-made tools as such, though the latter would be similar to email.

Answer (score -3):

You can `chmod` the file to allow everyone to write to the file, then ownership becomes less relevant.

`chmod 777 file` lets everyone do almost anything to that file.